# Primefaces: Timeline with fixed header

Tags: jsf, primefaces, timeline, primefaces-extensions

im working on a project using primefaces and its extensions including the timeline.

its not supported to have a fixed header on this (yet, i believe they plan on implement it) so i did it myself.

on my site i have 2 linked timelines, the only problem im facing is this:

http://s14.postimg.org/f9rhpkn1d/problem.png

when i change the viewport (drag and drop it to left/right or zoom in/out), the minor/major labels on the header dont get hidden, they still show until the complete day is not visible anymore

i tried fixing this with some z-index stuff, but no luck yet.

thanks in advance,

mike

Comment: You 'fixed' it yourself, but you still have a problem with it. Yet you don't post the code of your fix but still expect us to help... Can you please explain what and how you would help if you were us?

Comment: not much to do with Primefaces, more of a CSS issue....try applying 'overflow:hidden' to the parent header element

Comment: i kinda gave up on it, it was getting really ugly with lots of jquery code, and wasnt looking clean eighter so i decided to be a bit more patient and just wait for that feature to be implemented by the component

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well... there you go

not working for ie and only with pf5.1&extensions3.2.0

my 2 timelines have the ids timelineWeekly and timelineWeeklyBlocked and i put them inside a native scrollpanel with max height 450

code:

```
<h:outputScript id="connectTimelinesFixed" target="body"
            unescape="true" rendered="#{!weekTimelineController.isIE}">
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
    onrangechange2();
});
function onrangechange1() {  
    var range = PF('timelineOneWdgt').getVisibleRange();  
    PF('timelineTwoWdgt').setVisibleRange(range.start, range.end);
    var minorFirst = jQuery($(".timeline-selectable > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(19)"));
    var minorSecond = jQuery($("#timelineWeeklyBlocked > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(19)"));
    var majorFirst = jQuery($(".timeline-selectable > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6)"));
    var majorSecond = jQuery($("#timelineWeeklyBlocked > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6)"));
    var offsetRightMinor = ($(window).width() - (minorFirst.offset().left + minorFirst.outerWidth()));
    var offsetRightMajor = ($(window).width() - (majorFirst.offset().left + majorFirst.outerWidth()));
    var factorMinor = Math.round($(window).width()/offsetRightMinor).toFixed(1);
    var factorMajor = Math.round($(window).width()/offsetRightMajor).toFixed(1);
    console.log(factorMajor);
    if(factorMinor==12){
    minorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    minorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    } else if(factorMinor<12){
        minorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
        minorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    }
    if(factorMajor==12){
        majorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
        majorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    } else if(factorMajor==11||factorMajor==10){
        majorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
        majorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    }
}  

function onrangechange2() {  
    var range = PF('timelineTwoWdgt').getVisibleRange();  
    PF('timelineOneWdgt').setVisibleRange(range.start, range.end);
    var minorFirst = jQuery($(".timeline-selectable > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(19)"));
    var minorSecond = jQuery($("#timelineWeeklyBlocked > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(19)"));
    var majorFirst = jQuery($(".timeline-selectable > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6)"));
    var majorSecond = jQuery($("#timelineWeeklyBlocked > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(6)"));
    var offsetRightMinor = ($(window).width() - (minorSecond.offset().left + minorSecond.outerWidth()));
    var offsetRightMajor = ($(window).width() - (majorSecond.offset().left + majorSecond.outerWidth()));
    var factorMinor = Math.round($(window).width()/offsetRightMinor).toFixed(1);
    var factorMajor = Math.round($(window).width()/offsetRightMajor).toFixed(1);
    console.log(factorMajor);
    if(factorMinor==12){
    minorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    minorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    } else if(factorMinor<12){
        minorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
        minorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    }
    if(factorMajor==12){
        majorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
        majorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'hidden'});
    } else if(factorMajor==11||factorMajor==9){
        majorFirst.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
        majorSecond.css({'visibility' : 'visible'});
    }
}//]]>
        </h:outputScript>
        <h:outputScript id="JS" target="body" unescape="true"
            rendered="#{!weekTimelineController.isIE}">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(function($) {
var oldWidth = $(window).width();
var $cache = jQuery(".timeline-selectable > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
var $cache2 = jQuery("#timelineWeeklyBlocked > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)");
var top = 168;
var top2 = 635;
if(${weekTimelineController.browserCompatibility})
    top = 164,
    top2 = 630;
  function fixDiv() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var factor = oldWidth/viewportWidth;
    if(scroll > top)
      $cache.css({
        'top': '-'+(scroll-top)+"px",
        'margin-top': ''
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '-'+(scroll)+"px",
        'margin-top': top+'px',
        'z-index' : '1',
        'left': '*1.27'
      });
    if(scroll > top2)
      $cache2.css({
        'top': '-'+(scroll-top2)+"px",
        'margin-top': ''
      });
    else
      $cache2.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '-'+(scroll)+"px",
        'margin-top': top2+'px',
        'z-index' : '1',
        'left': '*1.27'
      });
  }
  $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
  $(window).resize(function() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var factor = oldWidth/viewportWidth;
    $cache.css({
        'left': '*'+factor*1.28
      }),
    $cache2.css({
        'left': '*'+factor*1.28
      });
});
  fixDiv();
});
//]]>
        </h:outputScript>
        <!-- css classes to set the height of the horizontal lines when header is fixed -->
        <h:outputStylesheet rendered="#{!weekTimelineController.isIE}">
#page {
    min-width: 800px !important;
}
div.timeline-axis-grid-minor {
    height: 428px !important;
}
div.timeline-axis-grid-major{
    height: 450px !important;
}
        </h:outputStylesheet>
```

looks like this:

http://s1.postimg.org/spfdd2bq7/image.png

i censored the names but u can see i scrolled down to the bottom and the header stayed fixed

i know its not especially elegant, but it was a requirement and i know theres other people that wanted to have this...